# txt преобразовать в массив с объектами

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый вечер! Очень нужна помощь. Есть файл txt http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/bradforddata.txt нужно как то его преобразовать в массив с объектами, для дальнейшего отображения через AngularJS, помогите плз

Comment: Для этого вам понадобиться какой-то серверный язык, желательно.

Answer (score 0):

Получить можно по ajax:

```js
fetch('http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/bradforddata.txt').then(response => response.text).then(text=> {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Если с CORS разберётесь, конечно.
Распарсил бы я как то так:

```js
const text = `Bradford
Location 414900E 435200N, Lat 53.813 Lon -1.772, 134 metres amsl
Estimated data is marked with a * after the value.
Missing data (more than 2 days missing in month) is marked by  ---.
Sunshine data taken from an automatic Kipp & Zonen sensor marked with a #, otherwise sunshine data taken from a Campbell Stokes recorder.
   yyyy  mm   tmax    tmin      af    rain     sun
              degC    degC    days      mm   hours
   1908   1    5.0    -1.4      21     ---    29.7
   1908   2    7.3     1.9       8     ---    71.9
   1908   3    6.2     0.3      13     ---   101.4
   1909   3    5.6    -0.3      17     ---    58.7
   1909   4   12.2     3.3       3     ---   188.9
   1909   5   14.7     4.8       2     ---   216.8
   1909   6   15.0     7.5       0     ---   139.5
   1909   7   17.3    10.8       0     ---   151.2
   1910   9   15.0     8.5       0     ---   106.1
   1910  10   12.6     7.3       0     ---    69.7
   1910  11    5.5    -0.4      17     ---    66.0
   1910  12    8.0     3.6       3     ---    24.0
   1911   1    5.8     1.8       6    33.0    23.5
   1911   2    6.9     1.3       8    91.7    65.8
   1911   3    6.4     1.9       2    25.1    83.6
   1911   4   10.0     3.9       3    26.4   128.3
   1911   5   16.3     7.9       0    24.6   192.3
   1911   6   17.8     9.0       0    84.3   225.3
   2017   7   19.9    11.8       0    74.2   172.0*  Provisional
   2017   8   19.0    11.3       0    59.8   175.3*  Provisional

`;
   
   
let fields;
console.log(text.split('\n').reduce((result,string) => {
  const words = string.split(/\s+/g);
  if(words.length === 8){
     if(fields){
          const obj = {};
          fields.forEach((field, index) => obj[field] = words[index]);
          result.push(obj);
     }else{
         fields = [...words];
     } 
  }
  return result;
}, []));
```